# searchbar и поиск по nsarray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Нашел великолепную [инструкцию](http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/08/18/searching-uitableview-with-uisearchdisplaycontroller/)  по поиску совпадение из массива через searchbar. Но выяснилось, что там есть недостаток. Например есть массив `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bar", @"foo", @"quux", @"foo1", @"foo2", @"foo3", @"foo4", nil];` Если в поисковой строке начать вводить "f", то вылезет табличка 'нет результатов', тоже самое будет и с "fo", а вот с "foo" он выдаст в результатах "foo". Как сделать, чтобы при вводе в строку "fo" он выдавал такой результат: "foo, foo1, foo2,foo3, foo4"?

Сам код:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        _items
          = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bar", @"foo", @"quux", nil];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayDelegate

// register a cell reuse identifier for the search results table view
-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
 didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
      forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"];
}

// perform the search
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    NSPredicate *predicate
      = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self = %@", searchString];
    NSArray *searchResults
      = [[self items] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [self setSearchResults:searchResults];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

// check if displaying search results
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
        return [[self searchResults] count];
    } else {
        return [[self items] count];
    }
}

// check if displaying search results
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell
          = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SearchResultsTableViewUITableViewCell"
                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
        id item = [[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:item];
        return cell;
    } else {
        UITableViewCell *cell
          = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"
                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
        id item = [[self items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:item];
        return cell;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

// manually perform detail segue after selecting a search result
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:cell];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UIViewController

/* prepare for detail scene segue
   called after cell selection in the master and 
   search results table views */
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;

    id item = nil;
    if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath
          = [[[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
        item = [[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    } else {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath
          = [[self tableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
        item = [[self items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }

    UIViewController *detail
      = (UIViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    [[detail navigationItem] setTitle:item];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условие для фильтрации задаётся в этой строке:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self = %@", searchString]
```

Если вам нужен фильтр "начинается с", то так и напишите:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self beginswith %@", searchString]
```

Также есть `contains`, `like` и прочие. Сейчас же у вас в условии стоит равенство.

См. [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).